# Github commit conflict

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit

In GitHub, I cloned version 1 of the repository and made changes in it. While I was making changes someone else also cloned the repository and made changes and committed the changes which are not on my local machine, now if I want to commit my changes then will their changes be retained or it will be overwritten by my code?

I want to merge both the codes such that changes of both of them are retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your changes won't override the other changes. There are 2 recommended ways to handle your case:

1. If your changes are in other files than the other changes just push and open a PR for your changes. It will merge the changes without problems.
2. If the changes are in the same files there's a risk of merge conflicts, that git can't automatically figure out what code to keep. In this case I suggest rebasing. This will make your changes go after the other changes.

2.1. `git checkout main` to use your local main branch

2.2. `git pull` to get the changes from origin into your local main branch

2.3. `git checkout your_branch` to use your branch

2.4. `git rebase main` to take your changes and move them to after the change. This might cause conflicts, if it does just follow the instructions to solve them.